# moving columns in gridview between template fields and bound fields

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq-to-sql, gridview

I have a gridview (GridviewProduct) in that i Have a Template field column Link button as Remove From Cart and and another Template Field column next to it as Quantity and other three Fields are boundField like ProductName, ProductPrice and ProductBrand. Which Looks as Follows:
[image]

I want to move the quantity column to the end of the gridview at the right hand side. when i use this code it gives me an error:

> *Insertion index was out of range*

```
 var Quantity = GridViewProduct.Columns[1];
 GridViewProduct.Columns.RemoveAt(1);
 GridViewProduct.Columns.Insert(5, Quantity);
```

please help.

Comment: do you require columno 1 and 2?if not then first set autogeneratecolumn=false

Comment: @Anuj: when i did that my boundField columns disappeared.. I have a datasource from linq2sql.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your requirement can be achieved in Gridview's RowCreated event

```
protected void GridView1_RowCreated(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
        {
            GridViewRow row = e.Row;
            List<TableCell> columns = new List<TableCell>();

            //Get the first Cell /Column
            TableCell cell = row.Cells[1];
            // Then Remove it after
            row.Cells.Remove(cell);
            //And Add it to the List Collections
            columns.Add(cell);

            // Add cells
            row.Cells.AddRange(columns.ToArray());
        }
```

Comment: thanks kundan.. when i was searching for an answer i came across ITemplate interface to add columns to gridview from server side will it be helpful to move columns.. i means this solution is excellent but will it?.

Comment: if i haven't found your answer.. i was going for it !

Answer (score 1):

If you have 5 columns and remove one of them, you have 4 left. The index of a new last column would than be 4 (since it is zero-based).

```
GridViewProduct.Columns.Insert(4, Quantity);
```

I am not sure if this removes all problems, but at least this error should go...

Comment: I would debug the code and check how many columns you have at the insert statement... perhaps something else is going wrong.